# Adding a Time Out / For Slide Out Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#nav-menu').bind("mousedown touchstart", function(){
        if ($('#patients-panel').hasClass('open')) {
            $('#patients-panel').animate({
                left: '-165px',
            }, 500);
            $('#patients-panel').removeClass('open');
            $('#nav-patients').removeClass('active');
        }
        slideMenu();
        $('#menu-panel').toggleClass('open');
        $('#nav-menu').toggleClass('active');
        swapImage();
    });
    $('#nav-patients').bind("mousedown touchstart", function(){
        if ($('#menu-panel').hasClass('open')) {
            $('#menu-panel').animate({
                left: '-165px',
            }, 500);
            $('#menu-panel').removeClass('open');
            $('#nav-menu').removeClass('active');
        }
        slidePatientMenu();
        $('#patients-panel').toggleClass('open');
        $('#nav-patients').toggleClass('active');
        swapImage();
    });
```

I would like to add a 3 sec timer to my Slide out Menu; So, essentially; after the menu 'Slides Out' it will slide back in within 3 seconds. How could I write this?

Comment: Have you looked at setTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is what you need to do, at the end of the callback functions that *"show"* the menu's, add this:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    $('#patients-panel').animate({left: '0px'}, 500);
},3000);
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set a setTimeout to call your "close window function"?

```
setTimeout(myCloseWindowFunction,3000);

....

myCloseWindowFunction(){
    //do stuff
};
```

You would just put the timer in each of your .bind functions.  It opens.. timer ticks down miliseconds and then calls a "closer" function

Comment: Noooooo don't call the function when calling `setTimeout`, pass a reference to the function! This won't work

Comment: Soooory .. my bad.  Tired.  I have corrected it to reference the function, although with a reference no arguments may be passed in.  I had originally wrote it as an anonymous function with another inside and then changed my mind.